# Block everything except 2 domains in Spam Assassin

Tags: linux, centos, spamassasin

One of our spamassassin servers is getting smashed by tons of Russian spam and causing a failure when we're trying to process the emails we care about. I'm trying to reject all email that isn't on 2 specific domains, but not sure why it isn't working properly.

I went through the config and added the following, but it doesn't see to make any changes after service restart.

In: `local.cf` i've tried 2 changes:

```
blacklist_to *@*
un_blacklist_to *@domain1.com
un_blacklist_to *@domain2.com
```

And this one...

```
whitelist_to *@domain1.com
whitelist_to *@domain2.com
blacklist_to *@*
```

I thought I would have seen some of these changes go through rather quickly but it doesn't seem to change anything. The spam email is coming in with pretty low sizes and the email I care about needs to be over 50k. Even if I could figure out how to reject all email over 50k, that would work.

Thanks for any help on this. Going to keep looking at solutions while in this bind...

Comment: Without further details on exactly what you're doing, this would seem to be a job for your MTA (e.g. postfix, exim, sendmail, etc) and not for SpamAssassin.  i.e. configure your MTA to accept only mail from those two domains you care about (and only for valid local/relay recipients, so you don't inadvertently create an open relay).

Comment: I have one server that is taking in emails via postfix and handling spam via spamassassin, then the good emails get sent to another server that runs postfix with scripts to push the images from those emails to another server. The spam assassin server is pushing a bunch of spam to the processing postfix server. Ill look in to only allowing emails TO certain@domains in postfix. As long as it has the correct domain in TO:, id be good. Thanks for the reply during this time :)